# Change UITableViewCell height after loading

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have custom UITableViewCell with UIWebView inside cell. UIWebView have default height constraint (20 px).

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var webViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {

       webView.frame.size.height = 1
       var contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize

       webView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height
       webView.scrollView.frame.size.height = contentSize.height

       webViewHeight.constant = contentSize.height

    }
}
```

Then I set what I want to load into webView. After loading UIWebViewDelegate call `webViewDidFinishLoad` , and I change height constraint. And at this moment I see constraints error in debug area.

```
2016-07-06 09:11:20.492 TEST CELL[1746:56476] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
 (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc087088f0 V:[UIWebView:0x7fbc0871eb70(50)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc086b46f0 UIWebView:0x7fbc0871eb70.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbc0871dea0.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc086b4740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbc0871dea0.bottomMargin == UIWebView:0x7fbc0871eb70.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc08700c10 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fbc0871dea0(59)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fbc087088f0 V:[UIWebView:0x7fbc0871eb70(50)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How I can set properly new constraint constant after loading?

Comment: What is the error that you see regarding the constraint?

Comment: Edited question content with error explanation.

Comment: i can solve your problem if you help me with this question, inside the cell what constraints you have given? is there any constraint which is 59 px from anywhere? remove it..and try...also don't forget to write [cell layoutIfNeeded]; after assigning new value to constraint.

Answer (score 1):

`webViewDidFinishLoad` can be called many times,  every time a frame is done loading so you must check this property:

```
if (webview.isLoading) {
    return
} else {
    // do my stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by pinning `webView` to top and bottom with constraints in  `TableViewCell` and then in your class with the `UITableView` this cell is displayed in, set

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And setting the height of the `webView` in `TableViewCell` as you are doing with constraint in `func webViewDidFinishLoad`.

This will give the cell the correct height so lastly you might want to use some delegate pattern to call the `UITableView` to reload (maybe just reload the indexPath for this cell).

Comment: Of Course I set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. In `func webViewDidFinishLoad` I set height for all webView frames (edited question. Up) and constraint. If I try reload `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)` webView reinitialized.